# How to create a laravel migration file manually

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a simple generator that will help me in my job to create models, controllers, views, routes, migrations with simple few lines of YAML.
Everything looks great till now but I had a problem and searched a lot about it but still get nothing.

My tool generates a migration file, the thing is the migration file name must follow specific rules so the `php artisan migrate` command can detect the file and migrate it.

the file name must start with the year, the month, the day and a number then the description of the migration.
for example. `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`
`2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php`
Now, It's easy to put the date in the beginning of the file, but how can I follow the number rules?
the number increases by one every new migration file.

How can I detect the last file created to know its number and make a new migration file with a number larger than the last migration file created?

Meantime I create the migration file name with this code.

```
$migrationFileName = date('y').'_'.date('m').'_'.date('d').'_'.'create'.ucfirst($name).'Table';
```

But the command `php artisan migrate` still cannot detect the file to migrate it without the number. So how can I do that?

Comment: Your `simple generator` is a console command?

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Migrations/MigrationCreator.php#L178

Comment: Thanks Winter.  It worked !

Comment: Does your class name begin with a number instead of a letter?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know what is actually the format for the naming of migrations file you should look at the **Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationCreator** file. The number you are guessing as an ordering is actually a timestamp which you can find in the following function in that file:

```
protected function getDatePrefix()
{
    return date('Y_m_d_His');
}
```

And following is the full filename creation function:

```
protected function getPath($name, $path)
{
    return $path.'/'.$this->getDatePrefix().'_'.$name.'.php';
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I got this error while trying to migrate
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '2016' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a number, it's current timestamp, like 143710. So, you could try something like this to get it:

```
Carbon::now()->format('His');
```

Comment: Using Carbon for this is unnecessary, `date('Y_m_d_His')` is sufficient for the entire date prefix and requires no external dependencies

Comment: Agreed, it'll give same result.

Answer (score 1):

It's Laravel's inbuilt mechanism. as soon as you create migration , the **naming_convention** will look a like **timestamps** and name of your table.

Or else you may use `Laravel Generator`. or you can use **Carbon** Timezone.